# Weird results from Blob Storage save action?

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am using the nodejs blob storage client to store a file in Azure blob storage.

```
return new Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
   _this.blobClient.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile("protofiles", path, e.file, function (error, result, response) {
       if (!error) {
          console.log("res: ", result);
          observer.next(result);
       }
    });
});
```

This returns the results in the following format:

```
res:  BlobResult {
   container: 'protofiles',
   name: 'data/d812a55b-5631-4b40-81a9-e80151533112',
   lastModified: 'Tue, 08 Nov 2016 12:14:29 GMT',
   etag: '"0x8D407D0CA7952D5"',
   requestId: 'ecfd5758-0001-0062-24b9-396984000000',
   contentSettings: { contentMD5: '846vto3oRsaB0whXPDpZVw==' } 
}
```

Which means the results have to first go through a process of string manipulation before JSON can be extracted out of this. This doesn't feel normal and I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this sort of weirdly formed data.

Edit:
I tried parsing the JSON on jsonlint.com and I get the following results:

[image: blobResult]

Comment: Not sure what your question is, or what you're referring to. What JSON are you trying to extract? The `res` object you showed looks like JSON to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` in the callback function is a [`BlobResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/models/blobresult.js) object. I am not sure what do you mean weird result, and also not sure what's your requirement. But As it is a object, you can directly get its properties in `result.{propertyName}`.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Liu Thanks for the response. Usually when printing objects it just prints the contents of the object and not the name of the object, especially since I have not created this object. I am not sure if this is a new behaviour from nodejs.